# Close bootstrap datepicker dialog when another datepicker input is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a list of bootstrap datepicker input boxes all using the same class of .datepicker. Dialog shows and udpates as expected. My problem is I want the previous datepicker dialog to close automatically when another datepicker input is clicked. Currently they all stay open. Attached is my very simple datepicker function.

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(e){
$(this).datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yy",
    autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

});

Do they each need a unique class/id for this to work? Let me know what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(".datepicker").mousedown(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler solution: just use a class that's not "datepicker" to target your inputs, e.g.:

```
<input class="dp" type="text" name="start_date" />
```

and:

```
$('.dp').datepicker();
```

Then it will have the behavior you want by default.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Note, this is also true of "datetimepicker" - literally any other CSS class, or id/name/element selector works fine. Seems to be because these classes are used internally by the JS plugin for the overlay, and not meant to be applied to the input element.

Answer (score 0):

Using id selectors instead of class makes it work. Different for each input of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, assuming you're using this one https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker :

```
$el.datetimepicker(options).on('dp.show', function (evntObj) {
    if ($el.attr('id') === 'startPicker') {
        var endPicker = $('#endPicker').data('DateTimePicker');

        if (endPicker.widget.is(':visible')) {
            endPicker.hide();
        }
    } else {
        var startPicker = $('#startPicker').data('DateTimePicker');

        if (startPicker.widget.is(':visible')) {
            startPicker.hide();
        }
    }
});
```